# Input dispatching timed out (ANR)(Waited 5000ms for MotionEvent)

Tags: java, android, crash, crashlytics, android-anr-dialog

I have published my app few days ago and in that so many ANR is generating.

Input dispatching timed out (cabef3d main.MainNavigationActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5000ms for MotionEvent)

Above is the ANR gnerating most of time

Below here I'm giving screenshot of both log of playstore and my code

[image: playstore log image]

[image: code image]

Comment: Also it may occur when debug. Just stop at breakpoint and wait for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are blocking the main thread. Make sure that IO operations such as db access is done in a thread other than the main thread. On top of that you may need to implement some basic Activity setup to allow the app to respond to inputs (hard to say with so little information provided).